# Expectation of SDE

Tags: integration, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations

I'm trying to get the Expected Value but I feel like I'm doing this wrong...

When I solved the SDE I got $\int W(t)dW(t)=(W^{2}(t)/2)-t/2$
I've Assumed the first bit =0 and so then I'm trying $0=E[(W^{2}(t)/2)-t/2]$
$0=E[(W^{2}(t)/2)]-E[t/2]$
but I dont think this is correct.
The original eq. was $X_t^{2}$

Comment: Please formulate complete questions. What SDE, and the expected value of what is to be computed? And indeed $E(W_t^2)=t$ is correct, even a defining property of the Brownian motion.